# Test class fails to call the method

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage

can someone help me to find the cause why my test class doesnt cover the method that is called in the test class, as seen in my test class I create an instance to call the method from the class.

But it covers only the first part of the query as seen in below image, it also doesnt cover this query part `AND Account.AccountCountry__c = 'PH' AND Account.TypeOfCompany__c = 'Agent / Broker'` while I have replicated the setting in my test class and thus since the next query returns 0 then the rest will not get covered.
[image]

```
@isTest
public class automatedCommunicationPHNewTest{

    @isTest(SeeAllData=true) 
    public static void automatedCommunicationPHT01(){
        List<Task> autoEmailTask;

         Account acc = new Account();
         acc.CurrencyIsoCode = 'PHP';
         acc.AccountCountry__c = 'PH';
         acc.TypeOfCompany__c = 'Agent / Broker';
         acc.LastRenewalNoticeDate__c = null;
         acc.ExcludeFromAutomatedSendouts__c = false;
         acc.Name = 'acc';
         acc.ProbableListings__c = 100;
         insert acc;

         Contact contact = new Contact();
         contact.LastName = 'Patrick';
         contact.Email = 'email';
         contact.ContactForContracts__c = TRUE;
         contact.AccountId = acc.Id;
         insert contact;

         Contract__c con = new Contract__c();
         con.AccountName__c = acc.Id;
         con.PayPeriod__c = 'Monthly';
         con.CurrencyIsoCode = 'PHP';
         insert con;

         ContractLineItem__c cli1 = new ContractLineItem__c();
         cli1.Contract__c = con.id;
         cli1.Stage__c = 'Active';
         cli1.StartDate__c = system.today().addMonths(-6).addDays(15);
         cli1.Duration__c = 6;
         cli1.CurrencyIsoCode = 'PHP';
         cli1.DurationType__c = 'Months';
         cli1.PricePerMonth__c = 10;
         cli1.TaxRate__c = '0';
         insert cli1;

         system.debug(acc.Contractsigneduntil__c);

         automatedCommunicationPHNew instance = new automatedCommunicationPHNew();
         instance.autoEmailSendout();

         autoEmailTask = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE WhatId =: acc.Id];
         system.assert(autoEmailTask.size()>0);


    }
}
```

My full code here

```
public class automatedCommunicationPHNew{

    public List<OrgWideEmailAddress> orgWideMail = [SELECT Id FROM OrgWideEmailAddress];
    public EmailTemplate ExpiringContract = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'New Renewal Notice' LIMIT 1];
    public EmailTemplate DueInvoice = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Invoice Due in 2 Weeks' LIMIT 1];
    public EmailTemplate BlockingOutstanding = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Blocking Outstanding' LIMIT 1];
    public EmailTemplate BlockingAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Blocking Account' LIMIT 1];
    public EmailTemplate DeactivatingAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'Deactivated Contract' LIMIT 1];
    public EmailTemplate PerformanceReport = [SELECT Id, Name, Description, Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =: 'New Performance Report PH' LIMIT 1];
    public Id emailtemplate;
    public String templateDescription;              // The template description will be assigned to the Task Subject of the task
    public String templateSubject;
    public Id invPDFattachmemt{get;set;}
    public Attachment attach{get;set;}
    public EmailTemplate template;
    public List<Invoice__c> linv;
    public String day = String.valueOf(date.today().day());
    public Decimal dday = [SELECT Id, GLRemainingQuota__c from Account WHERE Name =: 'Trash Account DO NOT DELETE'].GLRemainingQuota__c;  // used to simply being able to change the supposed sendout date of performance mail without changing and re-deploying the class

    public void autoEmailSendout(){
/**** Put here the sendouts that are active ****/
        this.sendRenewalReminder();
        this.sendInvoiceReminderAll();
        this.sendInvoiceReminderLimit();     

    }


    public void sendRenewalReminder(){
        String ReplyToEmail;

/**** Set Sender Name (as appears in client's mailbox) ****/
        String senderName = 'name';
        String defaultReplyEmail = 'email';   // used only if both Account Owner and Aftersales Managers are inactive in SF

/**** Set Template ****/

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

/**** Set filters and conditions (recipients and criteria -> To:, When?, who?, why?) ****/
        List<Contact> licontact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact
                            WHERE ContactForContracts__c = TRUE     // only contacts that are marked to receive contract info
                            AND Email <> ''
                            AND Account.ExcludeFromAutomatedSendouts__c = FALSE                 // Checkbox on account to exclude Account from sendouts
                            AND Account.Contractsigneduntil__c =: system.today() + 35           
                            AND Account.AccountCountry__c = 'PH' AND Account.TypeOfCompany__c = 'Agent / Broker' 
                            AND (Account.LastRenewalNoticeDate__c <: system.today() OR Account.LastRenewalNoticeDate__c =: null)];  // avoids multiple sendouts in case the method is called several times on the same day
        system.debug('aaa' + licontact.size());


/**** Start process ****/

        IF(licontact.size() >0){
            /**** Set parameters ****/
            List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.AccountManager__r.Email, Account.AccountManager__r.isActive, Account.Owner.Email, Account.Owner.isActive, Account.Contractsigneduntil__c
                                            FROM Contact WHERE Id in: licontact];
            FOR(Contact cont : contacts){
                ids.add(cont.Account.Id);
            }
            List<Account> accounts = [SELECT LastRenewalNoticeDate__c FROM Account WHERE Id in: ids];

            /**** Create emails ****/

            FOR(Contact cont : contacts){

                template = ExpiringContract;

                emailtemplate = template.Id;
                templateDescription = template.Description;              // The template description will be assigned to the Task Subject of the task
                templateSubject = template.Subject; 

                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                mail.setTemplateId(emailtemplate); 
                //mail.setSenderDisplayName(senderName);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(cont.Id); 
                mail.setWhatId(cont.AccountId);
                mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideMail[0].Id);

                IF(cont.Account.AccountManager__r.Email <> null && cont.Account.AccountManager__r.isActive == TRUE)
                   ReplyToEmail = cont.Account.AccountManager__r.Email;
                ELSE IF(cont.Account.Owner.Email <> null && cont.Account.Owner.isActive == TRUE)
                   ReplyToEmail = cont.Account.Owner.Email;
                ELSE
                    ReplyToEmail = defaultReplyEmail;      
                mail.setReplyTo(ReplyToEmail);       

                mails.add(mail);
            }

            system.debug(mails.size());
            system.debug(mails);

        /**** Send emails ****/
            IF(mails.size() >0){
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails, false);

                /***** updates Account date of last sendout to avoid multiple sendouts ****/
                FOR(Account acc : accounts){
                    acc.LastRenewalNoticeDate__c = system.today();
                }

                update accounts;
            }
        }
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void sendInvoiceReminderLimit(){
        String ReplyToEmail;

/**** Set Sender Name (as appears in client's mailbox) ****/
        String senderName = 'name';
        String defaultReplyEmail = 'email';   // used only if both Account Owner and Aftersales Managers are inactive in SF

/**** Set Template ****/

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

/**** Set filters and conditions (recipients and criteria -> To:, When?, who?, why?) ****/
        List<Contact> licontact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact
                            WHERE ContactForContracts__c = TRUE     // only contacts that are marked to receive contract info
                            AND Email <> ''
                            AND Account.ExcludeFromAutomatedSendouts__c = FALSE                 // Checkbox on account to exclude Account from sendouts
                            AND Account.Outstanding_Amount__c >:0     
                            AND 
                              (Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() + 14
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() + 7
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() - 7
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today()
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() - 14
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() - 28)
                            AND Account.AccountCountry__c = 'PH' AND Account.TypeOfCompany__c = 'Agent / Broker' 
                            AND (Account.LastInvoiceNoticeDate__c <: system.today() OR Account.LastInvoiceNoticeDate__c =: null)];  // avoids multiple sendouts in case the method is called several times on the same day
        system.debug('aaa' + licontact.size());


/**** Start process ****/

        IF(licontact.size() >0){
            /**** Set parameters ****/
            List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.AccountManager__r.Email, Account.AccountManager__r.isActive, Account.Owner.Email, Account.Owner.isActive, Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c
                                            FROM Contact WHERE Id in: licontact];
            FOR(Contact cont : contacts){
                ids.add(cont.Account.Id);
            }
            List<Account> accounts = [SELECT LastInvoiceNoticeDate__c FROM Account WHERE Id in: ids];

            List<Invoice__c> linv = [SELECT Id, NetAmount__c, Tax__c, TotalAmount__c, ServicePeriodStartDate__c, ServicePeriodEndDate__c, Account__c, Account__r.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c
                                     , InvoiceAutoNumber__c, Contract__c, Account__r.Name, Account__r.AccountCountry__c, Account__r.AccountLegalName__c, Account__r.TaxID__c
                                     , Account__r.BillingStreet, Account__r.BillingCity, Account__r.BillingState, Account__r.BillingPostalCode
                                     , Account__r.BillingCountry, Date_sent__c, Date_1st_reminder_sent__c, Date_2nd_reminder_sent__c 
                                    FROM Invoice__c 
                                    WHERE Account__c in: ids];

             Account parent = [SELECT Id FROM Account where Name =:'Trash Account DO NOT DELETE'];


            /**** Create emails ****/

            FOR(Contact cont : contacts){

                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() + 14) {

                    template = DueInvoice;
                } 

                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today()) {

                    template = DueInvoice;
                } 

                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() + 7){

                    template = DueInvoice;
                }
                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() - 7){

                    template = BlockingOutstanding;
                }
                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() - 14) {

                     template = BlockingAccount;
                }
                 if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() - 28) {

                     template = DeactivatingAccount;
                }

                emailtemplate = template.Id;
                templateDescription = template.Description;              // The template description will be assigned to the Task Subject of the task
                templateSubject = template.Subject; 


                system.debug('**linv**' + linv.size());

                FOR(Invoice__c inv : linv){

                    /// Create the pdf for attachment ///

                    if(inv.Account__c == cont.AccountId && inv.ServicePeriodStartDate__c == inv.Account__r.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c){

                        PageReference BillPDF = new PageReference('/apex/InvoicePDF' + inv.Account__r.AccountCountry__c);
                        String pdfname = 'temp';

                        BillPDF.getParameters().put('id', inv.Id);
                        attach = new Attachment();
                        Blob attachbody;
                        try{
                            attachbody = BillPDF.getContentAsPDF();
                        } catch (VisualForceException e) {
                            attachbody = Blob.valueof(pdfname);
                            }

                        attach.Body = attachbody;
                        attach.Name = 'Invoice' + inv.InvoiceAutoNumber__c + '.pdf';
                        attach.IsPrivate = true;
                        attach.ParentId = parent.Id;
                        insert attach;

                        invPDFattachmemt = attach.Id;

                    /// Attach pdf to mail ///

                        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                        efa.setFileName(attach.Name);
                        efa.setBody(attach.Body);


                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                        mail.setTemplateId(emailtemplate);
                        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideMail[0].Id); 
                       // mail.setSenderDisplayName(senderName);
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(cont.Id); 
                        mail.setWhatId(inv.Id);
                        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

                        IF(cont.Account.AccountManager__r.Email <> null && cont.Account.AccountManager__r.isActive == TRUE)
                        ReplyToEmail = cont.Account.AccountManager__r.Email;
                        ELSE IF(cont.Account.Owner.Email <> null && cont.Account.Owner.isActive == TRUE)
                        ReplyToEmail = cont.Account.Owner.Email;
                        ELSE
                            ReplyToEmail = defaultReplyEmail;      
                        mail.setReplyTo(ReplyToEmail);       

                        mails.add(mail);
                    }
                }
                system.debug('This is the run query: ' + Limits.getQueries());

                if(Limits.getQueries() >= Limits.getLimitQueries()){
                    break;
                }  
            }

            system.debug(mails.size());
            system.debug(mails);

        /**** Send emails ****/
            IF(mails.size() >0){
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails, false);

                /***** updates Account date of last sendout to avoid multiple sendouts ****/
                FOR(Account acc : accounts){
                    acc.LastInvoiceNoticeDate__c = system.today();
                }

                update accounts;
            }

        }
    }

   public void sendInvoiceReminderAll(){
        String ReplyToEmail;

/**** Set Sender Name (as appears in client's mailbox) ****/
        String senderName = 'name';
        String defaultReplyEmail = 'email';   // used only if both Account Owner and Aftersales Managers are inactive in SF

/**** Set Template ****/

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

/**** Set filters and conditions (recipients and criteria -> To:, When?, who?, why?) ****/
        List<Contact> licontact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact
                            WHERE ContactForContracts__c = TRUE     // only contacts that are marked to receive contract info
                            AND Email <> ''
                            AND Account.ExcludeFromAutomatedSendouts__c = FALSE                 // Checkbox on account to exclude Account from sendouts
                            AND Account.Outstanding_Amount__c >:0     
                            AND 
                              (Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() + 14
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() + 7
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() - 7
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today()
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() - 14
                            OR Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c =: system.today() - 28)
                            AND Account.AccountCountry__c = 'PH' AND Account.TypeOfCompany__c = 'Agent / Broker' 
                            AND (Account.LastInvoiceNoticeDate__c <: system.today() OR Account.LastInvoiceNoticeDate__c =: null)];  // avoids multiple sendouts in case the method is called several times on the same day
        system.debug('aaa' + licontact.size());


/**** Start process ****/

        IF(licontact.size() >0){
            /**** Set parameters ****/
            List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.AccountManager__r.Email, Account.AccountManager__r.isActive, Account.Owner.Email, Account.Owner.isActive, Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c
                                            FROM Contact WHERE Id in: licontact];
            FOR(Contact cont : contacts){
                ids.add(cont.Account.Id);
            }
            List<Account> accounts = [SELECT LastInvoiceNoticeDate__c FROM Account WHERE Id in: ids];

            List<Invoice__c> linv = [SELECT Id, NetAmount__c, Tax__c, TotalAmount__c, ServicePeriodStartDate__c, ServicePeriodEndDate__c, Account__c, Account__r.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c
                                     , InvoiceAutoNumber__c, Contract__c, Account__r.Name, Account__r.AccountCountry__c, Account__r.AccountLegalName__c, Account__r.TaxID__c
                                     , Account__r.BillingStreet, Account__r.BillingCity, Account__r.BillingState, Account__r.BillingPostalCode
                                     , Account__r.BillingCountry, Date_sent__c, Date_1st_reminder_sent__c, Date_2nd_reminder_sent__c 
                                    FROM Invoice__c 
                                    WHERE Account__c in: ids];

             Account parent = [SELECT Id FROM Account where Name =:'Trash Account DO NOT DELETE'];


            /**** Create emails ****/

            FOR(Contact cont : contacts){

                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() + 14) {

                    template = DueInvoice;
                } 

                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today()) {

                    template = DueInvoice;
                } 

                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() + 7){

                    template = DueInvoice;
                }
                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() - 7){

                    template = BlockingOutstanding;
                }
                if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() - 14) {

                     template = BlockingAccount;
                }
                 if(cont.Account.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c == system.today() - 28) {

                     template = DeactivatingAccount;
                }

                emailtemplate = template.Id;
                templateDescription = template.Description;              // The template description will be assigned to the Task Subject of the task
                templateSubject = template.Subject; 


                system.debug('**linv**' + linv.size());

                FOR(Invoice__c inv : linv){

                    /// Create the pdf for attachment ///

                    if(inv.Account__c == cont.AccountId && inv.ServicePeriodStartDate__c == inv.Account__r.Due_date_of_last_open_invoice__c){

                        PageReference BillPDF = new PageReference('/apex/InvoicePDF' + inv.Account__r.AccountCountry__c);
                        String pdfname = 'temp';

                        BillPDF.getParameters().put('id', inv.Id);
                        attach = new Attachment();
                        Blob attachbody;
                        try{
                            attachbody = BillPDF.getContentAsPDF();
                        } catch (VisualForceException e) {
                            attachbody = Blob.valueof(pdfname);
                            }

                        attach.Body = attachbody;
                        attach.Name = 'Invoice' + inv.InvoiceAutoNumber__c + '.pdf';
                        attach.IsPrivate = true;
                        attach.ParentId = parent.Id;
                        insert attach;

                        invPDFattachmemt = attach.Id;

                    /// Attach pdf to mail ///

                        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                        efa.setFileName(attach.Name);
                        efa.setBody(attach.Body);


                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                        mail.setTemplateId(emailtemplate);
                        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideMail[0].Id); 
                       // mail.setSenderDisplayName(senderName);
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(cont.Id); 
                        mail.setWhatId(inv.Id);
                        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

                /**** Set the email address to which the clients replies 
                      ** Aftersales manager by default
                          ** Account Owner if AS is inactive
                          ** default email address otherwise                    ****/
                        IF(cont.Account.AccountManager__r.Email <> null && cont.Account.AccountManager__r.isActive == TRUE)
                        ReplyToEmail = cont.Account.AccountManager__r.Email;
                        ELSE IF(cont.Account.Owner.Email <> null && cont.Account.Owner.isActive == TRUE)
                        ReplyToEmail = cont.Account.Owner.Email;
                        ELSE
                            ReplyToEmail = defaultReplyEmail;      
                        mail.setReplyTo(ReplyToEmail);       

                        mails.add(mail);
                    }
                }
            }

            system.debug(mails.size());
            system.debug(mails);

        /**** Send emails ****/
            IF(mails.size() >0){
                Messaging.sendEmail(mails, false);

                /***** updates Account date of last sendout to avoid multiple sendouts ****/
                FOR(Account acc : accounts){
                    acc.LastInvoiceNoticeDate__c = system.today();
                }

                update accounts;

            }

        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your query is returning 0 records.

Try populating acc.Contractsigneduntil__c with a value.

Comment: Hi ebar, Contractsigneduntil__c is automatically populate from cli1.Duration__c = 6; . I just get confused with the query check as I think I have populate everything in my test class but still the query returns 0

Comment: Well, seealldata is set to true. That means that neither your test record nor any records in your database meet that query criteria. If you run that query you will receive no records, take a look at your data quality.